# How to configure an OpenShift cluster with type ClusterIP with no session affinity?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, load-balancing

I have the below `service` deployed to openshift.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tika-server
    template: tika-server-template
  name: tika-server
  namespace: testns
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: manager
      port: 8889
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8889
    - name: worker
      port: 9001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9001
  selector:
    app: tika-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I want this service to have **no** session affinity.

So I have

```
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Which I was hoping would tell OpenShift that I want to be able to access this server through http://tika-server-testns.my.domain.com/status with absolutely no session affinity. Each request from a pod should be hitting all the servers.

But when I use this service, from other pods, I still see that there is cookie based session affinity happening. In other words, each request comes back with a cookie such as:

```
Cookie: 7110c3e5...6aa9f40c9=97f1b6daf76...18a6
```

And as a result, each pod that consumes this service sticks to a single node, which in my case is not desirable behavior. As a work-around, I'm having to disable cookies.

When I disable that cookie, I get the load balancing as expected.

What am I missing here? Do I need some other configuration parameter to disable this session affinity?

Comment: sessionAffinity on Service level is not using cookies but ip addresses for affinity. Session affinity with cookies that is most probably caused by ingress controller. What Ingress controller are you using? Can you provide ingress object yaml for this service?

Comment: I'm not using Ingress. This is pod-to-pod traffic inside the cluster only.